# Magento using setCurPage for reviews pagination

Tags: collection, query, pagination

I'm using the `allreviews` Magento extension so that I have a page with all reviews however I need to add pagination to this page.

The last bit I'm stuck with is essentially adding the limit to the query. I've read a number of threads that say to use `setCurPage` on the collection but this doesn't seem to affect the query at all?

When I try what should equal `LIMIT 25, 25` and `LIMIT 75,25` etc I still get the result from `LIMIT 0, 25`

**Current query:**

```
//$_GET['product'] = 1;    //product id
$numberOfReviews = 25;     //per page
$page = 3;                 //page

$_reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', $_GET['product'])
                        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
                        ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                        ->setDateOrder('desc')
                        ->setPageSize($numberOfReviews)
                        ->addRateVotes()
                        ->setCurPage($page);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `addRateVotes()` loads the collection, try `setCurPage()` before that call.

Once a collection has been loaded, no changes can be made to it without first clearing it.

```
    public function addRateVotes()
    {
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $votesCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option_vote')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->setReviewFilter($item->getId())
                ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addRatingInfo(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load();
            $item->setRatingVotes($votesCollection);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: `addRateVotes()` at the end seemed to do the trick, thanks!